# Call click() of RadButton in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, iframe, telerik

I have an iFrame, which contains a RadButton.
The ID is btnTest.

Now, I try to call the click-method of this RadButton from outside of the iFrame. I have tried:

```
function SaveClick() {
    var iframe = document.getElementById('ifr');
    alert(iframe.id);
    var doc = iframe.contentWindow.document;
    if(doc) {
        alert('aaa');
    }
    //var btn = doc.getElementById('<%=btnTest.ClientID %>');
    var btn = $find('<%=btnTest.ClientID %>', doc);
    if(!btn) {
        alert('bbb');
    }
    btn.click();
}
```

but nothing is working.

I can get the iFrame (the id of the iFrame is showing in the first alert) and also 'aaa' is showing in the second alert. But I cannot get the btn (the third alert with 'bbb' is also showing because of the not in the if).

Can someone help me please, how to get the control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a function in the page that you put in the iframe. This function will return a reference to the button.

```
var btn = iframe.contentWindow.getMyRadButton();
btn.click();
```

where getMyRadButton is something like

```
function getMyRadButton() {
 return $find("<%=RadButton1.ClientID%>");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You use `onclick`, for example:

```
document.getElementById("ele").onclick = function(){
    alert("Hello World");
}

document.getElementById("ele").onclick();
```

And you should have a function made for that elemenet for `onclick`.

http://jsfiddle.net/3RTGL/1/

Comment: ah yes - but the problem is before that mistake. I am not able to get the RadButton. The variable btn is always false.

Comment: Then I recommend variable checking, there is probably a small typing error. Be sure `<%=btnTest.ClientID %>` is defined in asp.

Comment: I have declared the Button in asp like `<julMD:JulitecSaveButton ID="btnTest" runat="server"></julMD:JulitecSaveButton>` where `JulitecSaveButton` inherits from Telerik `RadButton`.

Comment: The `JulitecSaveButton` has a attached Eventhandler in the CodeBehind on ServerSide which should be called at the end.

Comment: Note in jQuery that for ID's you need to have a `#` in front. Does this work: `$find('#'+'<%=btnTest.ClientID %>', doc);` ?